# Serverless deployed lambda not invoking callbacks.

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, amazon-cognito

I am pretty new to serverless and I have come across a bizarre situation. I have created a lambda function which lists the users from the cognito user pool. I have used `cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers` to get the user list from user pool.

I tried creating the lambda function using serverless framework. Everything works fine but the callback for `listUsers` is never triggered.There are no error logs in cloudwatch and nothing happens until it gets timed out. I tired creating a test function from lambda console directly and used the same code there and the test function works perfectly fine.I am getting the user list from the test function.

Can anyone please give me an idea of what is happening here. If you want any more info please let me know. I would be very happy to get it fixed. I don't want to have two mediums for handling the lambda function which I am currently having (both serverless framework as well as lambda console).

Comment: I actually had a similar problem, on my case it was something related to vpcs. Can you show how you are configuring you're serverless.yml? Also try to see if there's a difference beteween both lambdas

Comment: @dege I am not using any VPC's for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're trying to call an asynchronous method from inside your Lambda.

When AWS calls your Lambda, it simply invokes the handler method specified when you deployed the lambda. When that method returns, AWS puts the container that ran your code to sleep until another request is received.

In this case, what happened was probably you called the cognito list users call which is asynchronous and your main method ran to completion before receiving a response on the callback. AWS then put the container to sleep, which killed the connection to cognito and so you never received the response.

Unless there's a synchronous variant of the cognito list users call, then you'll either have to figure out how to make the call block and wait for the response in your code, or find another way to call cognito.

Since cognito is an AWS service, I'm pretty sure you are simply using the wrong SDK or API call variant to interact with cognito from inside the lambda.

Comment: Thanks for your useful info. I will do some more research on it. Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: I have one more doubt; If AWS works as per your info then why does it works when I created the function directly from the Lambda console and not works when deployed using the serverless framework.